# How to filter list depending on occurences within string

Tags: regex, powershell

I have an array of items like this:

```
get-childitem *\bin\Release\*Tests.dll -recurse
```

I have paths like these:

```
C:\r\x\ABCTests\bin\Release\net461\ABCTests.dll
C:\r\x\ABCTests\bin\Release\net461\OtherTests.dll
C:\r\x\OtherTests\bin\Release\net461\OtherTests.dll
```

I only want the paths that the name of the file matches the name of the folder:

```
C:\r\x\ABCTests\bin\Release\net461\ABCTests.dll - Yes
C:\r\x\ABCTests\bin\Release\net461\OtherTests.dll - No
C:\r\x\OtherTests\bin\Release\net461\OtherTests.dll - Yes
```

What would be the best way to filter this in Powershell? I have tried with Select-String but it opens the file. I have the regex expression ready for I'm having trouble in executing in in Powershell. Should I use regex?

Here is the powershell code:

```
get-childitem *\bin\Release\*Tests.dll -recurse | Where-Object { $_.FullName -match {"(" + $_.Name.Substring(0, $_.Name.LastIndexOf(".")) + ").*\1\.dll"} } | %{ write-host $_ }
```

Comment: Try with a regex pattern of the form `(.*)/path/to/foler/\1`. It will only match strings which have the same string in the beginning and end.

Comment: Edited and I have more problems with powershell than with regex

Comment: Try `$rx = '\\([^\\]*)Tests\\bin\\Release\\(?:.*\\)?\1Tests\.dll$'` regex and run it like `get-childitem *\bin\Release\*Tests.dll -recurse | Where { $_.FullName -match $rx } | % { $_.FullName }`. Have a look at https://regex101.com/r/oBBNnK/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using

```
$rx = '\\([^\\]*)Tests\\bin\\Release\\(?:.*\\)?\1Tests\.dll$'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oBBNnK/2).

**Regex details**

- `\\` - a `\` char
- `([^\\]*)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than a backslash
- `Tests\\bin\\Release\\`  - a `Tests\bin\Release\` text  (we may hardcode it since this value was used in the glob)
- `(?:.*\\)?` - an optional sequence of any 0 or more chars other than a newline as many as possible, and then a backslash
- `\1` - the same value as captured in Group 1
- `Tests\.dll` - `Tests.dll` string (we may hardcode it since this value was used in the glob)
- `$` - end of string.

Then use

```
Get-Childitem *\bin\Release\*Tests.dll -recurse | 
  Where { $_.FullName -match $rx } | 
    % { $_.FullName }
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oBBNnK/2).